# c++ win32 ejecutar codigo al dar click a un boton

Tags: c++, click, winapi

Tengo un boton con este codigo:

```
   HWND hwndButton = CreateWindowW(
   L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
   L"OK",      // Button text 
   WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
   10,         // x position 
   10,         // y position 
   50,        // Button width
   20,        // Button height
   hWnd,     // Parent window
   NULL,       // No menu.
   (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
   NULL);      // Pointer not needed.
```

el problema es que no se como ejecutar una funcion al dar click
si alguien me ayuda lo agradeceria

Answer (score 0):

El parámetro en el que se pide un puntero HMENU en un botón es la "ID de interacción" en GUIs hechos para win32.

```cpp
   HWND hwndButton = CreateWindowW(
   L"BUTTON"
   L"OK",
   WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 
   10,
   10,
   50,
   20,
   hWnd,
   (HMENU), // ID
   (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
   NULL);
```

Te recomiendo mantener un trazo de los botones que tienes, por ejemplo usando #define

```cpp
#define Boton1 5
CreateWindowW(...,
  (HMENU) Boton1,
  ...
);
```

Para agregar funcionalidad al botón en cuestión, necesitas que en la función que procesa los eventos (window procedure) de la ventana padre del botón, tengas registrado WM_COMMAND en tu lista de mensajes, y a su vez tener registrada la ID de tu botón adentro de WM_COMMAND.

```cpp
LRESULT WndProc(..., UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, ...) {
  ...
  switch(msg) {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
      switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case Boton1:
        {
          // Funcionalidad aquí
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
  ...
}
```